# Host connected to IPSec tunnel, docker not able to talk to VPN hosts

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, docker, ipsec

Host can ping hosts in vpn, docker container cannot ping any hosts that are in vpn.

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
3.210.122.60    192.168.100.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
172.17.0.0      192.168.100.86  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.18.0.0      192.168.100.86  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.19.0.0      192.168.100.86  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.20.0.0      192.168.100.86  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.21.0.0      192.168.100.86  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.22.0.0      192.168.100.86  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.23.0.0      192.168.100.86  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.24.0.0      192.168.100.86  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.25.0.0      192.168.100.86  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.26.0.0      192.168.100.86  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.41.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
```

tcdump showing the ping goes to the VPN, and it returns to host, but not to the container. I believe the host has no idea what to do with the package it receives back from the vpn.

I tried some iptables rules but to no avail.
Can't debug more than tcpdump...

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40

$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Comment: Can ya add what `iptables` rules you've tried already, and is that `route` command output from the perspective of the _host_ or _guest_ (Docker) OS? ... looks like it's from the host's perspective, which is not so helpful in debugging the network as seen by the guest OS.

Comment: The container route is simple, only having the default gateway `172.41.0.1`. The iptables did not affect the behavior in any way

Comment: Okay... re-reading your question it looks to be an issue with the `iptables` rules, if ya do end-up posting the output of `sudo iptables -S` from the perspective of both the host and the guest I'm pretty sure that help can be provided. There's quite a bit that could be blocking or misdirecting the connection attempts... also because the guest isn't directly connected to the VPN it'll have to be _notified_ that there's additional routes available, well that is if ya want to ping that network range from the guest; seems to be what this is all about.

Answer (score 0):

After changing networking on the host, including connecting to a VPN, try restarting the docker daemon (`systemctl restart docker`). The daemon configures various iptables rules when it first starts up which may not work when new networks are attached to the host.

Comment: Did that and it did not work.